# Count paths with Topological Sort

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, graph, topological-sort

I have a DAG and I need to count all the paths since any node to another node, I've researched a little bit and I found that it could be done with some Topological Order, but so far the solutions are incomplete or wrong.

So how is the correct way to do it?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to count all of the paths in a tree/DAG. Here is the pseudocode:

```
function numPaths(node1, node2):
    // base case, one path from node to itself
    if (node1 == node2): return 1

    totalPaths = 0
    for edge in node1.edges:
        nextNode = edge.destinationNode
        totalPaths += numPaths(nextNode, node2)

    return totalPaths
```

**Edit:**
A good dynamic approach to this problem is the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).

Comment: Well that's the first thing I did, but it seems to be too slow. That's why I researched and find this Topological Sort thing.

Comment: Why would topological sort help you with counting the paths? It is meant to convert a non-DAG to a DAG, not simplify counting.

Comment: Because this naive recursion does a lot of redundant work on some DAGs. If you memoize, the memoization table ends up being built in topological order.

Comment: Ok I understand. I will try to fix the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a DAG you can topologically sort the nodes in O(V+E) time. Let's assume the source vertex is S. Then from S start traversing the nodes in depth first fashion. When we're processing node U , let's assume there's an edge U->V then V is of course not yet visited (why? because it's an directed acyclic graph) So you can reach from S to V via node U in d[U] ways where d[U] is the number of paths from S to U.

So number of paths from S to any node V, d[V] = d[x1]+d[x2]+d[x3]+ . . . +d[xy], where there are edge like x1->V, x2->V, . . . xy->V

This algorithm will take O(V+E) to topologically sort the graph and then for calculating number of paths at most O(V*E ). You can further reduce its run time of calculating number of path to O(V+E) using adjacency list instead of adjacency matrix and this is the most efficient solution so far.

Comment: IT has to iterate the topological sort list in the opposite direction?

Comment: @bones.felipe: no, from the root towards leaves. . .

Comment: But for example, if I have this topological list: 0-2-1-3 where in addition 0->1 and 2->3 it counts 5 no?

Comment: ok so `d[0]=1;` and from 0 we get `d[2]=d[2]+d[0]=1` and `d[1]=d[1]+d[0]=1`. Then we go to 2, From 2 `d[1]=d[1]+d[2] = 2` and `d[3]=d[3]+d[2]=1` Then we go to 1, it has only 1 edge 1-3, so `d[3]=d[3]+d[1]=2+1=3` So from 0 ~> 3 there are 3 different paths :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Assume G(V,E)
Let d[i][j] = the number of all the paths from i to j
Then d[i][j]= sigma d[next][j] for all (i,next) in E
```

It seems too slow? Okay. Just memorise it(some guys call it dynamic programming). Like this

```
memset(d,-1,sizeof(d))// set all of elements of array d to -1 at the very beginning
saya(int i,int j)
{
    if (d[i][j]!=-1) return d[i][j];//d[i][j] has been calculated
    if (i==j) return d[i][j]=1;//trivival cases
    d[i][j]=0;
    for e in i.edges
        d[i][j]+=saya(e.next,j);
    return d[i][j];
}
```

Now saya(i,j) will return the number of all the paths from i to j.

Comment: what are you memoizing here? As it's a DAG, i=>j won't occur twice :-)

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the top down approach :)